# Ad software to rotate text links?

Tags: advertising, looking-for-a-script, openx

I am currently using OpenX to rotate text links but I don't think search engines can spider these links. What software can I use to do this?

Comment: Keep in mind that if Google thinks you're selling links and not using nofollow on them then you run the risk of having your pages banned or having them not PR or have any SEO value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want search engines to spider the results then your best bet is to rotate them on the server-side in whatever programming language and framework you are using (PHP, Rails, etc).

John is absolutely correct that if you are selling the links then you want to be careful about them being indexed as google will penalize you.

Comment: Note that this may involve nothing more than changing what form of the OpenX invocation code you use(assuming you're using the Javascript version, like most do). It's been a while since I had to use that app, but there should be an option that functions server-side. Make sure to check any compatibility/behavior changes, though.